# comparing image from ui to sqlite database image

Tags: ios, sqlite, uiimage

I want to make an application in ios which has image in imageview and a database with thousand of images which will be used for comparing the image that is currently in image view

for. eg: suppose i have some celebrity's image in imageView.. then i have to compare this image with sqlite database and show the most appropriate image/list of image that is matching with it.

this is just a raw idea, have still not started working on it so i can not show any code

Is there any open source library in ios which i can use for achieving this??? or can someone guide me some links for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Open source library found, I created my own logic using OpenCV and storing images in database. I used [Pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) concept to solve the large amount of data to be processed
Thank you